# Apply an ICC Color Profile to an image in C# (Dotnet)

Tags: c#, .net, gdi+, color-management

How does one convert an image from one color profile to another (screen to printer, or scanner to screen).  In Visual C++ you would use the function in ICM.h, is there a managed way to do this with GDI+?

I need to use GDI+, not WPF.  I'd prefer to have a managed solution, but if it is not available, I guess PInkvoke will have to suffice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of solutions.

1. For GDI+, [check out this article at MSDN](https://web.archive.org/web/20090224151626/http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317825/) (HOW TO: Use GDI+ and Image Color Management to Adjust Image Colors).
2. For WPF (.NET 3.0), see the [System.Windows.Media](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.color.colorcontext(VS.85).aspx) namespace. There are a number of different classes, such as the [BitmapEncoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapencoder.aspx), that have the concept of a [ColorContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colorcontext.aspx), which "Represents the International Color Consortium (ICC) or Image Color Management (ICM) color profile that is associated with a bitmap image."

Both of these seem pretty complex, so there's always the option of buying somebody else's code.  Atalasoft's [DotImage Photo Pro](http://www.atalasoft.com/products/dotimage/photopro/default.aspx) has ICC profile setting capabilities built in.  The code is expensive; a dev license is almost 2k.  But based on their participation in the dotnet community, I'd give them a whirl.

Comment: The MSDN link is dead

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at [Lcms](http://www.littlecms.com/). Its a colour management system, fairly complete, but written in C. you can use pinvoke, but I would recommend Managed C++ wrapper. I am actually currently working on a managed wrapper around the engine (just the basics, colour profile conversion, lab readings). I can post a link to the code after i am complete. It may be a week or so though.

Comment: Please do send a link as soon as you are finished!  That sounds perfect.

Comment: Mattlant, Do you ever completed managed wrapper for lcms. If yes, mind posting it somewhere? Thank you.