# How apply Color Lut over bitmap image in c#

Tags: c#, imaging

I am opening different types of images like (8 and 16 bit) and they are (Monocrome, RGB ,palette color).

I have raw pixel data of these images.
 I create bitmap like this for 8 bit images.

```
          //for monocrome images i am passing PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed.
          //for RGB images i am passing PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb
           PixelFormat format = PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed;
           Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Img_Width, Img_Height,format);

           Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, Img_Width, Img_Height);

           //locking the bitmap on memory
           BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, format);

           // copy the managed byte array to the bitmap's image data
           Marshal.Copy(rawPixel, 0, bmpData.Scan0, rawPixel.Length);
           bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
```

---

The problem is that when i draw that bmp image then it differs in color than original.
So is there any way to apply lut (lookup table) on that colored images.

i want any unsafe code because i tried getixel and setPixel and they are very slow.
I also dont want Image.fromSource() methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved this problem see how.
Somewhere i read that GDI+ return BGR value not the RGB.
So i reverse the order and amazing everything fine.
But it is little bit slow.

```
       PixelFormat format = PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed;
       Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Img_Width, Img_Height,format);

       Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, Img_Width, Img_Height);

       //locking the bitmap on memory
       BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, format);
       Marshal.Copy(rawPixel, 0, bmpData.Scan0, rawPixel.Length);

       int stride = bmpData.Stride;
       System.IntPtr Scan0 = bmpData.Scan0;

       unsafe
       {
           byte* p = (byte*)(void*)Scan0;
           int nOffset = stride - bmp.Width * SAMPLES_PER_PIXEL ;
           byte red, green, blue;

           for (int y = 0; y < bmp.Height; ++y)
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < bmp.Width; ++x)
                {
                    blue = p[0];
                    green = p[1];
                    red = p[2];
                    p[0] = red;
                    p[1] = green;
                    p[2] = blue;
                    p += 3;
                }
                p += nOffset;
            }
        }

        ////unlockimg the bitmap
        bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
```

thanks

Can anybody is having some faster code than that.

Comment: Hi,
Also its only working for RGB images.
Because RGB images having all the three component (R,G,B).

What about PaletteColor images.
I am unable to understand the indexing of color in palette images.
Are anybody handle Palette Color images.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the bitmap's [`Image.Palette`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.palette.aspx) property.

Comment: I saw that but for RGB images Image.palette is 0.
I am getting Image.Palette = 256 in case of monochrome and Palette color images.

But for palette color images how can i get RGB byte array separately
and how to apply on Image.Palette.

I tried that but suppose Original image is in Green color.
And i am getting image color violet from my code.

So are it gives original green color if i will take separate RGB and apply on Image.palette.
Thanks

Comment: I don't know where you're getting your source data from, but you should be able to _write_ to the palette thus: bmp.Palette.Entries[0].r = red_value; etc.  ImagePalette is a "ColorPalette" object, not just the number of entries.

Comment: thanks,
irst of ColorPalette is sealed class so you can't make palette from own.If image is not having.
bmp.Palette is a property.But you can't set direct values on that.
Because if bmp.Palette = 0 so their is no any entries.
So if you trying bmp.Palette.Entries[i]  give you out of bound exception.

And if want to set bmp.Palette.Entries[i].R  is a read only property.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, .NET does not support ICC color profiles, so if you for instance open an image that is using the AdobeRGB color profile, the colours will appear a bit duller and more "greyish" than if you open the same image file in, say, Photoshop or another color-profile-aware software.

[This post discusses some color profile issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38295/apply-an-icc-color-profile-to-an-image-in-c-dotnet); you may find something of interest there.

Comment: I am getting image.Palette = 256 for Palette color and monochrome images.
But how can i reflect these palette to image.
Because image looks incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

GetPixel and SetPixel are indeed very slow. If you want to do operations on single pixels, consider using a [FastBitmap](http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid6CB7C8C7E03A6E0FCE7B30E360E77F0AF6B23DF0.aspx). It allows to quickly color pixels. Using this unsafe bitmap will greatly improve your speed.