# Getting color image from bitmap while image is 16bppGrayscale

Tags: c#, bitmap, imaging

Problem No1.
[My own Related problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/797659/how-apply-color-lut-over-bitmap-image-in-c)

I asked the next question here

Now the Problem No 2 is.

When i am trying to open 16 Bit (Monocrome ) images from their raw pixel data
then i am getting Error.
Because i am using PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayscale on creation of Bitmap like

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Img_Width, Img_Height,PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayscale);
```

So googled and found Format16bppGrayscale not supported so i modifed my code like below.

```
 PixelFormat format = PixelFormat.Format16bppRgb565;
 Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(Img_Width, Img_Height, format);
 Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, Img_Width, Img_Height);
 BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, format);
 Marshal.Copy(rawPixel, 0, bmpData.Scan0, rawPixel.Length);
 bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
```

Amazing thing is that i am getting the image now because i change the pixelFormat.
But problem is that My monocrome (Grayscale) image look in various color.

How can i get the original appearance. I tried several grayscale method but not successful
Please give me some unsafe code.
Thanks,

Comment: Does this help? http://www.eggheadcafe.com/forumarchives/NETFrameworkdrawing/Nov2005/post24405677.asp

Answer (score 2):

[BobPowell's GDI+ FAQ has a bit about greyscale](https://web.archive.org/web/20141230145627/http://bobpowell.net/grayscale.aspx). The 16 bpp in .NET just doesn't work. I have to do everything in 32 bpp and resort to external tools for conversion. Luckily (?) I get to stick with TIFF images most of the time.  Also, [this thread](http://bytes.com/groups/net-c/270353-format16bppgrayscale-not-supported) might help.

Comment: I previously saw that post.
I saw BobPowell faqs and tried that code.
Images color are just changed to some random color but not in grayscale.

I also saw that post from bytecode.
He is asking same thing as me.
I also working for medical images.

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the pallet to a greyscale pallet.  The default pallet for 8bppIndexed is 256 colour.  You can change it like this:

```
ColorPalette pal = myBitmap.Palette;

for (int i = 0; i < pal.Entries.Length; i++)
    pal.Entries[i] = Color.FromArgb(i, i, i);

myBitmap.Palette = pal;
```