# Loading bitmap with ICM profile

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, gdi+, printers

I am working on a sample in this I am loading a EMF file. To do this I am using API

```
Image image = Image.FromFile(strFilePath, true);
```

The 2nd parameter is to use the embedded ICM profile. Then I am trying to read the each pixel.
Then I made the 2nd parameter to false and read the pixel. 
In both the cases I am getting the RGB values as same.

Actually I want to convert RGB to YCMK. While doing so some one told me to use the ICM profile.
Can any body tell me how to laod the image with ICM profile in C# .net

Answer (score 0):

I think the first answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38396/47589) will help you.